# How to Update Flatlist item which is in previous screen and Update from current Next screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on Messaging App. There is Two screens First is List of Users with last message. Next one is chat screen like whatsapp. i create chat functionality using socket.ioclient. but when i recieve message i want to update last message of Users list which is in previous screen.

What i do is refresh hole page on back click but it takes too much time to load list of users. so is there any solution to update Flatlist of previous page from current screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pubsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js) to update the previous screen

Subscribe Pubsub in first screen

```js
PubSub.subscribe('UpdateList', (msg, data) => {
  this.setState({
    isRestaurantApp: data.Messages
  })
})
```

Publish Pubsub from socket service where you received the messages

```js
PubSub.publish('UpdateList', { 'Messages': [] })
```

Comment: i will try it and tell you. thanx for this.

Comment: Can you tell me name of the library

Comment: I have added it PubSub. I have given its link as well in my answer.